# Can I have text selected in div while having textbox focused for input?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm looking for possibility in html to keep always focused input, while having possibility to select and copy text from other parts of the page. I'd like to model it, that when user copies anything from the page and pastes it, it automatically goes to the place that was lately selected (would be best: to the place, where is the text cursor).

What I've found is that I can listen to keyboard events on document and emulate them on the input (so if there's keypressed with "A", I'd add "A" to last saved position in the textbox). The problem here is repeating exactly what is done by textbox implementations and the fact that I can't emulate text cursor.

Maybe there is some editor component, that would make it possible?

Comment: Then how is the browser supposed to do the selection when you focus on the textbox forever.

Comment: It may be bogus focus in the textbox, that's somehow switched between selection, css styling of selected text... I'm looking for any direction to make it work the way I want. Some unix terminal emulators got such behaviour and I'd like to recreate it in html+css+js.

Comment: The only thing you could do is, add an "onpaste" handler on the document and get the copied data and paste it into the textbox

Comment: I think you'd have to store a reference to the target input box in a variable, attach an event to the window object on keyDown and then trap ctrl+V.  You could setFocus to the input box.